# How to make a screenshot of an embedded iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, screenshot

I want to have a function that make a snapshot of the iframe and append to the other area of the webpage. The codes should look like:

Html:

```
<iframe src="http://edition.cnn.com/video"></iframe>
<button id="btn_screenShot" name="screenShot">Grab a image</button>
<div id="screenShot-result"></div>
```

JS:

```
function screenShot(iframe) {
   //what can I do here?
   //transform the page in <iframe> to a image type, jpeg,png or any other!
}

$('#btn_screenShot').click(function(){
   var imgPath = screenShot(document.getElementByTagName('iframe'));
   $('#screenShot-result').append("<img src=\"+ imgPath +\">");
});
```

First, it doesn't work with html2canvas, like the limitation described.
Is there any other javascript or jquery plugin to realize the function? or is it possible to work like the print-screen button on the keyboard?

Comment: This is impossible. Think of the maliciousness capable with such a methodology.

Comment: Look for same origin policy. It's impossible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: firefox extensiond can do screenshots, and ARE made with js, but i don't think that's the droid you're looking for...

Comment: Why would this be maliciousness? I need the same feature right now. I'm using a snapshot service right now but it's not the droid i'm looking for...